# Cannot access Result property of a Task

Tags: c#

I think i initialized the "Task(TResult)" well, but it is sending this error : 'Task' does not contain a definition for 'Result' and no extension method 'Result' accepting a first argument of type 'Task' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

I'm in .net 4.0. It's the 'MySqlParameter[] param = tu.Result;' line which is producing the error.

```
   Task < MySqlParameter[] > td3 = new Task < MySqlParameter[] > (() = >{
    MySqlParameter[] param = {
        new MySqlParameter("nom", MySqlDbType.String) {
            Value = textBox2.Text
        },
        new MySqlParameter("nom_a", MySqlDbType.String) {
            Value = textBox3.Text
        },
        new MySqlParameter("code", MySqlDbType.String) {
            Value = textBox4.Text.ToUpper()
        },
        new MySqlParameter("ok", MySqlDbType.String) {
            Value = textBox85.Text.ToUpper()
        }
    };
    return param;
});
td3.ContinueWith(tu = >{
    MessageBox.Show(this, Properties.Resources.f_ann + ": \n" + tu.Exception.GetBaseException().Message);

},
new CancellationTokenSource().Token, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
td3.ContinueWith(tu = >{
    string sqlm = "update filiere set nom=@nom," + "nom_a=@nom_a, codef=@code" + " where codef='@ok'";
    MySqlParameter[] param = tu.Result;
    conn.Open();
    MySqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(conn, sqlm, param);
    td4.Start();
},
new CancellationTokenSource().Token, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion); * *strong text * *
```

Comment: Can you post a compilable code? There is no ContinueWith taking 3 arguments

Comment: @PatrickHofman Can you please show me which one of the overloaded method from **.Net 4.0** API I should use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?view=netframework-4.0 - I cannot see any matching method - so OP has an error in code or description

Comment: @SirRufo You are right. I miscounted the brackets. I found the solution in the process though ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You picked the wrong overload (there are just 39 of them). There is no overload with 3 arguments, and the compiler trips over it:

```
td3.ContinueWith
    (tu =>
        {
            MySqlParameter[] param = tu.Result;
        }
    , new CancellationTokenSource().Token
    , TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion
    , TaskScheduler.Default
    );
```

Adding `TaskScheduler.Default` as the last argument does the trick.